# BE AJAX request delivers empty repository

Tags: typo3, extbase, typo3-4.5

I want to build an BE extension that is reading the repository from another extension and delivers the data as CSV/XSL/XSLX without saving it on the server. e.g Outputs the data in a blank window with modified headers.

The BE AJAX request is fired properly with

`$TYPO3_CONF_VARS['BE']['AJAX']['tx_myext::ajaxID'] = 'filename:object->method';`

The repository if called from the backend does work fine too.

```
public function ajaxAction() {
...
$this->extRepository =& t3lib_div::makeInstance('Tx_MySecondExt_Domain_Repository_DataRepository');
...
}
```

but when called from `domain.tld/typo3/ajax.php?ajaxID=tx_myext::ajaxID`
it doesnt find `Tx_MySecondExt_Domain_Repository_DataRepository` also if i call the repository of the second repository with the `findAll()` methode directly by AJAX. It does only return NULL.

also when setting the QuerySettings by hand

```
public function findAllexport() {
    $query = $this->createQuery();        
    $query->getQuerySettings()->setRespectStoragePage(FALSE);

    return $query->execute();
}
```

Also FYI its on 4.5

Edit:

Calling the repository with the ObjectManager doesn't work too

```
$objectManager = t3lib_div::makeInstance('Tx_Extbase_Object_ObjectManager');    
$this->extRepository = $objectManager->get('Tx_MySecondExt_Domain_Repository_DataRepository');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you make sure that the other extension is loaded before your own extension is loaded? Look at your `localconf.php`. Normally you need to specify the dependencies in your `ext_emconf.php` before you install your extension.

Also make sure that you have added both extension's configurations to the Static Includes of your TypoScript template.

Comment: ext_emconf.php dependencies are set , localconf.php does only contain
`$TYPO3_CONF_VARS['BE']['AJAX']['tx_myext::ajaxID'] = 'filename:object->method';`

But im not sure about the TS template, i'll check that later.

Comment: I didn't mean `ext_localconf.php` in your extension directory, but `typo3conf/localconf.php`. You can see the order of the extensions loaded at `$TYPO3_CONF_VARS['EXT']['extList']` and `$TYPO3_CONF_VARS['EXT']['extList_FE']`

Answer (score 0):

inside the export action

```
... Repository to file generation

header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="data.xls"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
// If you're serving to IE 9, then the following may be needed
header('Cache-Control: max-age=1');
// If you're serving to IE over SSL, then the following may be needed
header ('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT'); // Date in the past
header ('Last-Modified: '.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s').' GMT'); // always modified
header ('Cache-Control: cache, must-revalidate'); // HTTP/1.1
header ('Pragma: public'); // HTTP/1.0

... output file
exit;
```

done, no ajax plus pretty simple and stupid ;)

still if somone knows a awnser to the intial probelem i would appreciate it.